# SpringMVC REST Web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest

i am already starting using Spring framework and already i came across some kind of stupid problem ( but in fact i can't solve it) I have controller which looks like:

```
package org.springframework.rest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String returnHtmlPage() {

        return "page";

    }

}
```

where page is page.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
</body>
</html>
```

but insteed of HTML file i have only string "page" returned. How can i fix the problem?

Comment: remove the `@ResponseBody` :) So are you creating a REST service or a Web App?

Comment: i cannot believe it! almost 1,5h spent on this! thanks you Boris ! About question, right now i am discovering Spring framework, after this i will try to create REST service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code would print out just "page" (because of @ResponseBody). It does not return web page for you. you can use "ModelAndView" instead of "String" as your method output. And set your jsp page name (=page) there. something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView returnHtmlPage(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("page");
                /* here you can put anything in 'model' object that you
                   want to use them in your page.jsp file */
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This video will walk you through all the steps to build a RESTFul service using Spring MVC and then consume it using jQuery.http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/springmvc-intro You need to have the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver configured correctly as well.